# runner object doesn't exist during an event emit testing

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, unittesting

EDIT June 28 2023: When I removed `import '@openzeppelin/hardhat-upgrades';` from hardhat.config.ts, then whether I use `ethers.getContractFactory` or `ethers.deployContract` there is always `runner.provider` exists .

```js
// 1. deployContract use case
const myContract = await ethers.deployContract("MyContract", []);  await MyContract.waitForDeployment();

console.log(`deployed MyContract has runner :${myContract.runner}`);  // there is an object. Good!

// 2. getContractFactory use case
const MyContractFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyContract"); 
const myContractDeployed = await MyContractFactory.deploy();

console.log(`deployed myContractDeployed has runner :${myContractDeployed.runner}`);  // there is an object. Good!
```

So, now I am doubting `@openzeppelin/hardhat-upgrades`. This might override something unexpected and remove `runner` object. (But I need for upgradeable contract)

---

I am a bit confused where the issue comes from during my unit testing an event emit of a contract and it has been working until I change my code.

Working code:

```js
// myContract.test.ts
...
const myContract: MyContract;

beforeEach(async() => {
  myContract = await ethers.deployContract("MyContract", []);
  await MyContract.waitForDeployment();

  console.log(`deployed MyContract has runner :${myContract.runner}`);  // there is an object. Good!
});

it('should emit an event', async() => {
  await expect(MyContract.someFn())
  .to.emit(MyContract, "MyEvent")  // test passes
  .withArgs(42);
});
...
```

Then, I updated my code in order to implement upgradeable contract by using `@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable`. Then I can't test an event anymore.

Not working code:

```js
const myContract: MyContract;

beforeEach(async() => {
  const MyContractFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyContract");  // changed a deployment method from 'deployContract()'

  myContract = await upgrades.deployProxy(
      MyContractFactory,
      [], 
      {
        initializer: "initialize",
        kind: "transparent",
      }
    )

    await myContract.deployed();

  console.log(`deployed MyContract has runner :${myContract.runner}`);  // undefined. Not good :/
});

it('should emit an event', async() => {
  await expect(myContract.someFn())
  .to.emit(myContract, "MyEvent")  // test fails
  .withArgs(42);
});
...
```

I see that `deployContract()` returns an object that contains `runner` while `getContractFactory()` is not. But that's the only way I know deploying a upgradeable contract.

Because there is no `runner` object, then when I run `emit()` method during the testing, I end up here [emit.ts](https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/blob/main/packages/hardhat-chai-matchers/src/internal/emit.ts#L100):

```js
if (contract.runner === null || contract.runner.provider === null) {
  throw new errors_1.HardhatChaiMatchersAssertionError("contract.runner.provider shouldn't be null");
}
```

The fundamental question would be what's the difference between `deployContract()` and `getContractFactory()`? And how can I test an event while I use `getContractFactory()`.

FYI,
my package.json:

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^3.0.0",
    "@typechain/ethers-v6": "^0.4.0",
    "@typechain/hardhat": "^8.0.0",
    "hardhat": "^2.15.0",
    "typechain": "^8.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.9.2",
    "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable": "^4.9.2"
  }
```

hardhat.config.ts:

```json
import { HardhatUserConfig } from "hardhat/config";
import "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox";
import '@openzeppelin/hardhat-upgrades';

const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  solidity: "0.8.19",
};

export default config;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For me, the problem was as simple as I was not providing the Signer to the the contract I was using on even; in your example: `.to.emit(myContract, "MyEvent")` should be `.to.emit(myContract.connect(await ethers.provider.getSigner()), "MyEvent")`.
I don't think that's the issue you are having, but just in case someone stumble upon the same error, that was my case.

Answer (score 0):

In upgrades

```
console.log(`deployed MyContract has runner :${myContract.address}`);
```

Comment: Both myContract.address are printed out.